# Warning about missing signal in VHDL process sensitivity list

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga, quartus

I'm currently designing a simple multiple input SPI master in Quartus. Given it is a serial protocol, I have a serial clock and a signal that stores the current bit index.

One of the processes I have written looks like this:

```
store_bits : process(bit_clk) is
begin
    if rising_edge(bit_clk) and bit_index >= LEADING_BITS and bit_index < LEADING_BITS+DATA_BITS then
        data_valid <= '0';

        for input in 0 to INPUTS-1 loop
            data(input)(bit_index - LEADING_BITS) <= spi_miso(input);
        end loop;

        if bit_index = LEADING_BITS+DATA_BITS-1 then
            data_valid <= '1';
        end if;
    end if;
end process store_bits;
```

Now, `bit_index` is incremented in a separate process on the falling edge of `bit_clk`. The process above **shouldn't** be sensitive to `bit_index` transitions, so I've left it out of the sensitivity list.

Unfortunately, Quartus II throws a warning during analysis:

> 10492 VHDL Process Statement warning at multi_spi.vhd(68): signal "bit_index" is read inside the Process Statement but isn't in the Process Statement's sensitivity list

Is it correct? Should I add it to the sensitivity list even though the actual process will only do anything when there is also a `bit_clk` rising edge?

Comment: Try to separate the `if` condition into 2 if conditions:

    if rising_edge(bit_clk) then
      if bit_index >= LEADING_BITS and bit_index < LEADING_BITS+DATA_BITS then
        data_valid <= '0';
        ...

Comment: That totally fixed it. So, was the problem that Quartus isn't aware of logic "short circuiting", or was there a problem with my code?

Comment: Your code looks syntactically fine to me. Seems like a Quartus issue..